# Select getting separated from options using jquery .get

Tags: jquery, append

Some how my options are getting seperated from my dropdown and I don't know why. It's coming through ok. If I alert(data) before or after appending it to that div it shows them together, but then for some reason it gets messed up during the append.

```
/* add category dropdown */
jQuery('#add_category').live("click", function(){
    jQuery.get("add_dropdown.php", { cat_num: cat_num },
    function(data){
        jQuery('#add_category').remove();
        jQuery('#added_categories').append(data);
        jQuery("#drop"+cat_num).selectbox("attach");
        cat_num += 1;
    });
});
```

here's the add_dropdown.php

```
<?php 
include('database.php');
include('logged_in.php'); 
?>
<p>
    <label>Additional Category</label>
    <span class="field">
        <select name="cat<?php echo $_GET['cat_num']; ?>" class="longinput" id="drop<?php echo $_GET['cat_num']; ?>"/>
            <option value=""></option>
            <?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM product_categories WHERE website_id='".$website_info['id']."' ORDER BY sub_of ASC");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['name']."</option>";    
            } ?>
        </select>
        <a id='add_category' style='cursor: pointer;'>+ add one</a>
    </span>
</p>
```

Comment: I'm not a PHP programmer, so I may just be misreading it, but at the end of your `<select` line, do I see a `/>`? That would definitely cause your options to not be part of it since the select tag is closed.

Comment: @MrOBrian: I didn't notice that.  That's an HTML thing, not a PHP thing, but yes that would cause a problem.  Methinks that's the problem here.  Good eye :)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that it was converting the already closed select.

Comment: Quick additional: Any idea why it might only be allowing me to select the first option in the additional ones?